# Postgres Truncate command: how to check it is successfully executed python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working on python web app. I am using `postgres` database through `psycog2`.
I am making a table empty using command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE some_table_name RESTART IDENTITY;
```

I have an `IDENTITY`column in the table. I read that it returns the `identity` number. I have `cursor` object but didn't find any property for this.

How to check that the command is executed successfully?

Comment: If the command didn't throw an error, it was executed successfully.

Comment: 1) Where did you read it returned the number? The docs [Truncate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) don't say that and `truncate identity_test restart identity; TRUNCATE TABLE` backs that up. 2) If a command actually returned something you would need to fetch it: `cur.execute("insert into identity_test (fld_1) values ('test') returning id") cur.fetchone() (1,)`

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thanks. As you suggested, I think use `try except` block and return status as `boolean` from it.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks. I was reading the official docs only but seems I miss-interpreted it. As it says it resets the identity, I interpreted as It returns the identity number. Your way seems more precise.